# Removing a specific line of code from multiple Python files

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm currently trying to remove a specific keyword argument from multiple Python files and I'm using the `re` package to try and remove it; however, every time I try to do the regex substitution it doesn't remove it all.

An example file `foo.py` which might look like the following:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import test_utils as tu

test = tu.generate_graph(
   graph_type='line',
   thickness=300,
   color='blue',
   save=True,
   data=pd.read_csv('bar.csv')
)
```

I want to remove all instances of `thickness=300` and `save=True`

I did the following:

```
import re

target_strs = ['thickness=300','save=True'] 
open_file = open('foo.py', 'r')
read_file = open_file.read()
regex = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % ''.join(target_strs))
read_file = regex.sub('', read_file)
write_file = open('foo.py', 'w')
write_file.write(read_file)
write_file.close()
```

When I print out the new file content it gives me the same result as the original. 
Do I have to account for the tabs and new line strings when regex matching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to compile each instance separately.

Something like the following will work:

```
import re

target_strs = ['thickness=300','save=True']
open_file = open('foo.py', 'r')
read_file = open_file.read()
for e in target_strs:
    regex = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b' % ''.join(e))
    read_file = regex.sub('', read_file)
write_file = open('foo_test.py', 'w')
write_file.write(read_file)
write_file.close()
```

Notice that there are some fix that you might want to do:

1. Add the `,` to the regex otherwise it will raise later errors this is done be: `re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b\,' % ''.join(e))`
2. Add the unnecessary spaces, `\s`, like the following: `regex = re.compile(r'\b(?:%s)\b\,\s' % ''.join(e))`

In total after the above changes you will get the following output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import test_utils as tu

test = tu.generate_graph(
   graph_type='line',
      color='blue',
      data=pd.read_csv('bar.csv')
)
```